# Python Pandas - Json to DataFrame

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe

I have a complicated Json File that looks like this:

```
{
  "User A" : {
     "Obj1" : {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2",
        "key3": "val3",
     }
     "Obj2" : {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2",
        "key3": "val3"
     }
  }
  "User B" : {
     "Obj1" : {
        "key1": "val1",
        "key2": "val2",
        "key3": "val3",
        "key4": "val4"
     }
  }
}
```

And I want to turn it into a dataframe that looks like this:

```
                key1   key2   key3   key4
User A   Obj1   val1   val2   val3    NaN
         Obj2   val1   val2   val3    NaN
User B   Obj1   val1   val2   val3    val4
```

Is this possible with pandas? If so, how can I manage to do it?

- If it's easier, I don't mind removing the first two columns of the User and the Obj, and just remain with the columns of the keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can first read file to `dict`:

```
with open('file.json') as data_file:    
    dd = json.load(data_file)

print(dd)
{'User B': {'Obj1': {'key2': 'val2', 'key4': 'val4', 'key1': 'val1', 'key3': 'val3'}}, 
'User A': {'Obj1': {'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1', 'key3': 'val3'}, 
'Obj2': {'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1', 'key3': 'val3'}}}
```

And then use `dict comprehension` with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df = pd.concat({key:pd.DataFrame(dd[key]).T for key in dd.keys()})
print (df)
             key1  key2  key3  key4
User A Obj1  val1  val2  val3   NaN
       Obj2  val1  val2  val3   NaN
User B Obj1  val1  val2  val3  val4
```

Another solution with [`read_json`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_json.html), but first need reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and remove `NaN` rows by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dropna.html). Last need [`DataFrame.from_records`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_records.html):

```
df = pd.read_json('file.json').unstack().dropna()
print (df)
User A  Obj1     {'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1', 'key3': 'val3'}
        Obj2     {'key2': 'val2', 'key1': 'val1', 'key3': 'val3'}
User B  Obj1    {'key2': 'val2', 'key4': 'val4', 'key1': 'val1...
dtype: object

df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.values.tolist())
print (df1)
   key1  key2  key3  key4
0  val1  val2  val3   NaN
1  val1  val2  val3   NaN
2  val1  val2  val3  val4
```

---

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame.from_records(df.values.tolist(), index = df.index)
print (df1)
             key1  key2  key3  key4
User A Obj1  val1  val2  val3   NaN
       Obj2  val1  val2  val3   NaN
User B Obj1  val1  val2  val3  val4
```

Comment: you are so helpful thank you! can't imagine I worked an hour for something that can be done with two lines of code, so elegant... Is there a simple way to also save this df as an excel file?

Comment: Thank you for accepting! Sure, use [`to_excel`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) - `df1.to_excel('file.xlsx')` or `df1.to_excel('file.xlsx', index=False)` if need remove index.